# Kotlin SearchView how to adjust back button

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, searchview, back-button

when I search the recyclerview item with my app's search bar after I see the recyclerview item It should have gone back to recyclerview list when I press back button but app closes itself instead of that.

Here is my codes ;

```
//SEARCH
    searchBtn.setOnClickListener {
        url = ""

        postArrayList = ArrayList()
        postArrayList.clear()

        val query = searchEt.text.toString().trim()
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(query)){
            loadPosts()
        } else {
            searchPosts(query)
        }
    }
```

What can I do for this ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use onBackPressed button. Detail information is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Comment: But I'm still in same activity so It doesn't work